# Solarium filter query with OR

Tags: solr, solarium

I want to create a filter query with Solarium, using a lot of ORs.  The sql equivalent would be

```
select * from myTable where myValue in (1,3,5,6,9);
```

The string that I have created for my filter query is this:

```
spr:1 OR spr:3 OR spr:5 OR spr:6 OR spr:9
```

When I execute the query, this  error is thrown:

```
Exception: Solr HTTP error: OK (400) {"error":{"msg":"undefined field text","code":400}}
```

There is no doubt that the field exists in my schema and that it contains the correct values.  Using solr admin, I can manually execute the filter query and get the expected results.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?  Naturally I'd be happy to post more info, if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be an old question, but a solution is doing it like this:

```
spr:(1 OR 3 OR 5 OR 6...)
```